# If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I need to prove that if $f$ is Riemann integrable $[0,1]$ then $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)= \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$

My idea is to recognize the right side defining the limit as a Riemann sum and use the uniform continuity.

I am not sure what to do next

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your idea should work. Start by splitting [0,1] into $n$ segments of length $\frac{1}{n}$ each and use this as a partition.

Comment: If you're assuming that $f$ is Riemann integrable, then you shouldn't need uniform continuity—just recognizing that the expression inside the limit on the left-hand side is a Riemann sum should be enough.

Comment: What's your definition of Riemann integrability?

Comment: @rtybase, could you please explain it more? I started to prove it with 1/n<ẟ. Then I try to express this : 1/n∑f(k/n)-∫fdx

Answer (score 4):

Take the following partition
$$x_0=0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{2}{n}<\frac{3}{n}<...<\frac{n-1}{n}<x_n=1$$
or $x_k=\frac{k}{n}$.

Now, the left [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k-1})(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)$$
And the right [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k})(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
Combining this with the fact that $f$ is [Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums) (this is given) the limits of both left and right sums exist and are equal to $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$. To understand this properly, it is important to understand the definition of Riemann integrability, which operates with "For $\forall \varepsilon >0$, there $\exists\delta$ such that for **any partition** ...", which also includes the one constructed above.