# Proof verification for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n}) = +\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Show that: 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n}) = +\infty
> $$

I've tried the following way. Consider the following sum:
$$
\sqrt n + \sqrt{n-1} + \dots + \sqrt{n-\frac{n}{2}} + \dots + \sqrt{2} + 1
$$

Now if we take only $n\over 2$ terms of the sum we obtain that:
$$
\sqrt n + \sqrt{n-1} + \dots > {n \over 2} \sqrt{n\over 2}
$$
Let:
$$
x_n = {1 \over n}(1 + \sqrt{2} + \dots + \sqrt{n}),\ \ n\in \Bbb N
$$

Using the above we have that:
$$
x_n > {1\over n} {n\over 2}\sqrt{n\over 2} = {1\over 2}
\sqrt{n \over 2}
$$
Now taking the limit for RHS its obvious that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over2}\sqrt{n\over2} = +\infty
$$
Which implies:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = + \infty
$$

Have I done it the right way? Also i would appreciate alternative ways of showing  that limit. Thanks!

Comment: It's a very good way to do it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's seems fine, the more straightforward alternative way is by [**Stolz-Cesaro**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), that is

$$\frac{1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n+1}-(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n})}{n+1-n}=\sqrt{n+1}$$

As another one alternative, we can use AM-GM

$$\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n}) \ge \sqrt[2n]{n!}$$

Comment: Indeed that's a nicer way! Thanks. I'm not sure I am allowed to use that, since proving Cesaro-Stolz is introduced a couple hundred problems later. Otherwise definitely +1

Comment: @roman ok I try to add also another way!

Comment: Some idea for $\sqrt[2n]{n!}$?

Comment: yes, for example using Stirling's, or by showing $n! > \sqrt{n^n}$, i've solved a similar problem like half an hour ago

Comment: @roman We can also avoid Stirling using "Ratio-Root criterion", discussed [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3022553/505767) if you are interested.

Comment: I don't consider S-C more straightforward.

Comment: @zhw. Do you mean that AM-GM is preferable? or some other way?

Comment: I think the way the OP aproached it is the most straightforward.

Comment: @zhw. Ok of course but my answer is about "the more straightforward alternative". I'm not comparing that with the OP solution.

Comment: It read to me like you were saying "I have an alternative approach that is more straightforward"

Comment: @zhw. Ah no sorry that's was not my intention and of course it depends about the knowledge one has. Indeed note I've said "the more straightforward" and not "a more straightforward". That's was exactly my intention.

Answer (score 8):

$\bigl(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n}\bigr) $ is an *upper* Riemann sum, with the subdivision $\{0,1,2,\dots ,n\}$, for the integral $\;\displaystyle \int_0^n\sqrt x\,\mathrm d x=\frac23n^{3/2}$,so
$$\frac1n\bigl(1+\sqrt2+\dots + \sqrt{n}\bigr)\ge\frac1n\int_0^n\sqrt x\,\mathrm d x=\frac23\sqrt n,$$
which tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Where does the $1/n$ come from in that integral?

Comment: It's  $\Delta x$.

Comment: isn't delta x equal to 1 for that subdivision? I think you can make the argument work on the interval [0,1] but the Riemann sum won't be the exact given expression.

Comment: @Ned: Sorry, I completely messed up the argumentation. I've fixed that. Thanks for pointing the problem!

Answer (score 3):

In style to @Bernard's answer, but using [this general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118515/if-f-is-riemann-integrable-on-0-1-then-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-f/) (and very useful) trick
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)= \int\limits_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$
where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}= \int\limits_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}dx=\frac{2}{3} \tag{1}$$
Now
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}=\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}\right)\overset{(1)}{>}\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{2}{3}-\varepsilon \right) \tag{2}$$
from some $n_0$ onwards. And the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

The proof you've given is also the one I would have given (because it uses minimal resources), so I won't suggest an alternative - it just needs a little tweaking.

First, there's a minor typo: in two places, you've written $\sqrt{n + 1}$, where you meant $\sqrt{n - 1}$.

More seriously, you've assumed that $n$ is even: it doesn't make sense to talk of "$\frac{n}{2}$ terms" when $n$ is odd. This is easily remedied, because the idea of the proof is sound. One fix is as follows, although you may find a neater way:

Either $n = 2k - 1$ or $n = 2k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. The last $k$ terms of the sequence $1, \sqrt{2}, \ldots, \sqrt{n}$ are $\sqrt{n - k + 1}, \sqrt{n - k + 2}, \ldots, \sqrt{n}$. The  smallest term is $\sqrt{n - k + 1}$, which is either $\sqrt{k}$ or $\sqrt{k + 1}$. Therefore, the sum of the $k$ terms is at at least $k\sqrt{k}$. Therefore it is at least $\frac{n}{2}\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$, because $k \geqslant \frac{n}{2}$.

---

Here's another simple idea, using only the very easily proved AM-GM inequality for two terms:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{n - k + 1}}{2} \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[4]{k(n - k + 1)} \geqslant n^{5/4},
$$
because $k(n - k + 1) - n = (k - 1)(n - k) \geqslant 0$. Although very weak, it's enough for the job. (But I still prefer the solution given in the question.)

---

Looking for a proof using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, all I could come up with was this:
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k - 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k - 1}} > \frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}} \quad (1 \leqslant k \leqslant n), \\
\therefore\ 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < 2\sqrt{n}; \\
\text{but }
\left(1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n}\right)
\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \geqslant n^2,
\text{ by C-S}; \\
\therefore\ 1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n} > \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{2}.
\end{gather*}

---

I came up with the following quite long but elementary argument as a
way of avoiding the use of Jensen's inequality.

For all $k \geqslant 1$, we have

> $$
> \sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k} < \sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k - 1},
> $$

because
$$
\left(\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k - 1}\right)^2 = 2k + 2\sqrt{k^2 - 1}
< 4k.
$$

> **Lemma**
>   If $n > 2$, and
>   $a_2 - a_1 > a_3 - a_2 > \cdots > a_n - a_{n - 1} > 0$,
>   then
>   $$
> \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n}{n} > \frac{a_1 + a_n}{2}.
> $$

*Proof*
Write $b_k = a_{k+1} - a_k$, so that $(b_k)_{1 \leqslant k < n}$ is
a strictly decreasing sequence.
For all $k$ such that $1 < k < n$, we have
\begin{gather*}
\frac{a_n - a_1}{a_k - a_1} =
\frac{b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{n-1}}{b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{k-1}}
= 1 + \frac{b_k + b_{k+1} + \cdots + b_{n-1}}
{b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{k-1}} \\
\leqslant 1 + \frac{(n - k)b_k}{(k - 1)b_{k-1}}
< 1 + \frac{n - k}{k - 1} = \frac{n - 1}{k - 1}.
\end{gather*}
Setting $h = (a_n - a_1)/(n - 1)$ and $a_k' = a_1 + (k - 1)h$, we
therefore have $a_1 = a_1'$, $a_n = a_n'$, and $a_k > a_k'$
($1 < k < n$), whence
$$
a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n > a_1' + a_2' + \cdots + a_n' =
n\frac{a_1' + a_n'}{2} = n\frac{a_1 + a_n}{2},
$$
as required.
$\square$

Taking $a_k = \sqrt{k}$ in the lemma, we get
$$
1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n} >
\frac{n\left(\sqrt{n} + 1\right)}{2} \quad (n > 2).
$$

(Even after all this, I still prefer the OP's own proof - but
looking for alternatives is fun.)

---

Here is another quite simple proof, which I think I prefer to
the one given in the question. (Looking at the other answers, I see that it is a variant of a proof that Barry Cipra has already posted, but there are probably enough differences to make it still worth posting.)

If $n \geqslant 4$, there is a unique positive integer $r$ such that
$(r + 1)^2 \leqslant n < (r + 2)^2$, and:
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{=} 1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n}
\\ & \geqslant 1 + (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}) + \cdots
+ (\sqrt{r^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{(r + 1)^2})
\\ & > 0 + (2^2 - 1^2) \cdot 1 + (3^2 - 2^2) \cdot 2 + \cdots
+ ((r + 1)^2 - r^2) \cdot r
\\ & > 2 \cdot 1^2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + \cdots + 2 \cdot r^2
\\ & = \frac{1}{3}r(r + 1)(2r + 1) > \frac{2}{3}r^3
\\ & > \frac{2}{3}\left(\sqrt{n} - 2\right)^3.
\end{align*}

Although there's no need (for present purposes), one could also
argue that for all $n$, there is a unique positive integer $s$ such
that $(s - 1)^2 < n \leqslant s^2$, and:
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{=} 1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n}
\\ & \leqslant 1 + (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}) + \cdots
+ (\sqrt{(s - 1)^2 + 1} + \cdots + \sqrt{s^2})
\\ & \leqslant (1^2 - 0^2) \cdot 1 + (2^2 - 1^2) \cdot 2
+ (3^2 - 2^2) \cdot 3 + \cdots + (s^2 - (s - 1)^2) \cdot s
\\ & < 2 \cdot 1^2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + \cdots + 2 \cdot s^2
\\ & = \frac{1}{3}s(s + 1)(2s + 1) < \frac{2}{3}(s + 1)^3
\\ & < \frac{2}{3}\left(\sqrt{n} + 2\right)^3.
\end{align*}

Comment: Well, that is reasonable. Thank you for the notices, i appreciate that! Also i've fixed the typos, thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative, note first that the sequence is increasing:

$$\begin{align}
{1\over n+1}(1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1})-{1\over n}(1+\sqrt2+\cdots\sqrt n)
&={\sqrt{n+1}\over n+1}-{1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt n\over n(n+1)}\\
&\gt{\sqrt{n+1}\over n+1}-{n\sqrt n\over n(n+1)}\\
&={\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\over n(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Now consider

$$\begin{align}
{1\over n^2}(1+\sqrt2+\cdots+\sqrt{n^2})
&\gt{1\over n^2}(1+1+1+2+2+2+2+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)+n)\\
&={1\over n^2}(3\cdot1+5\cdot2+7\cdot3+\cdots+(2n-1)(n-1)+n)\\
&\gt{2\over n^2}(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2)\\
&={2\over n^2}\cdot{(n-1)n(2n-1)\over6}\\
&={(n-1)(2n-1)\over3n}\\
&\to\infty
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just another way assuming that you already heard about generalized hormonic numbers.*

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k=H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Now, the asymptotics
$$H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2 n^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{n^{1/2}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24n^{1/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}
   \right)$$ So, for large values of $n$,
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k } n=\frac{2 n^{1/2}}{3}+\frac{1}{2n^{1/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}
   \right)$$ which answers the question but also gives an approximation.

Fo raxample, using $n=100$, the exact calculation would give $\approx 6.71463$ while the above formula would give $\frac{403}{60} \approx 6.71667$ (relative error $=0.03$%).