# Evaluating $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|1+\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{N})|^2$ for $N \ge 3, N \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've tried to write it in complex exponential form to see if I could spot any geometric series, which led me nowhere near a solution. Mathematica evaluates it to  $\frac{3}{2}$, any idea on how to arrive to this result?

Comment: Use [Riemann sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118515/if-f-is-riemann-integrable-on-0-1-then-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-f/)

Comment: and maybe some trig identity would help with that. $\cos{2\theta}=2\cos{^{2}\theta}-1$ so in your case $1+\cos{(2\frac{k\pi}{N})}=2\cos{^{2}(\frac{k\pi}{N})}$. so you can lose the absolute value

Comment: @rtybase: no limit evaluation is asked.

Comment: @Bernard, but it [evalueates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%281%2Bcos%282*pi*x%29%29%5E2+dx) to $\frac{3}{2}$, as per the question.

Comment: The integral evaluates to $3/2$, but as I understand it, it's a formula depending on $N$ which is asked.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/N)$. Then
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}N\right)=\frac{\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}}{2}$$
and then
$$\left|1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}N\right)\right|^2
=\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}N\right)\right)^2
=\frac{(\zeta^k+2+\zeta^{-k})^2}{4}
=\frac{\zeta^{2k}+4\zeta^k+6+4\zeta^{-k}+\zeta^{-2k}}{4}.$$
Sum this from $k=0$ to $N-1$. The sums $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\zeta^{\pm 2k}$
and $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\zeta^{\pm k}$ are GPs which vanish (why?) leaving one
with
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left|1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}N\right)\right|^2=\frac{6N}{4}$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: do some trigonometry first: by the linearisation formulæ,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|1+\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{N})|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\Bigl(1+2\cos \frac{2k\pi}{N} +\cos^2 \frac{2k\pi}{N}\Bigr)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\Bigl[1+2\cos \frac{2k\pi}{N} +\tfrac12\Bigl(1+\cos \frac{4k\pi}{N}\Bigr)\Bigr].$$

Now you have a formula for the sum of cosines (or sines) in arithmetic progression, which you may prove via the complex exponential:
$$1 + \cos \theta +\cos 2 \theta + \dots + \cos n \theta  = \frac{\sin \cfrac{(n +1) \theta }{2}}{\sin \cfrac{ \theta }{2}}\,\cos \frac{n \theta }{2}  $$